# Compare files with similar names by size between folders

Tags: bash, text-processing, sort

I have two folders with thousands of files each. One folder from last year with a letter and the year prefix for each file (a2020abc123.txt), and the same file for this year in another folder with the same format (a2021abc123.txt). I need to compare the two folders to locate any files that have an egregious difference between last year and this year. My team has been doing this **by hand** so I would like a faster and less error-prone method.

For example:

```
/folder1/a2021fileA123.txt 50kb
/folder2/a2022fileA123.txt 80kb
```

```
/folder1/a2021fileA124.txt 79kb
/folder2/a2022fileA124.txt 80kb
```

```
/folder1/a2021fileA125.txt 90kb
/folder2/a2022fileA125.txt 80kb
```

Ideally would return something like:

```
/folder1/a2021fileA123.txt 50kb
/folder2/a2022fileA123.txt 80kb
/folder1/a2021fileA125.txt 90kb
/folder2/a2022fileA125.txt 80kb
/folder1/a2021fileA124.txt 79kb
/folder2/a2022fileA124.txt 80kb
```

I need the pairs of files to remain grouped together like above, which is the problem I have run into with the basic sorting I know how to do. I am very new to using tools like awk, and my team prefers powershell. Thanks so much. I'll be seeing these filenames in my dreams for weeks.

Comment: You say in your subject `Compare files with similar names by size between folders` - does that mean you just want to know if the size of the files differs between directories ("folders" is a Windows term) regardless if the contents of the files differs or not? You say you want to find an `egregious difference` so please define what `egregious` means to you - 10 bytes or more? 10 k? something else?

Comment: The size of the files are expected to differ by around 5-10kb larger or smaller. I am trying to locate any files that have a difference around 10kb ("egregious"). The files match each other between directories, a 2021 version in one folder and a 2022 version in the other:  (a2021file123.txt vs. a2022file123.txt), (a2021file124.txt vs. a2022file124.txt), etc. I can put them all in one directory if that helps. The goal is to identify any files that have a difference 10kb (larger or smaller) than last year. The files are around 50kb each and there are around 20k in each directory. Thanks!

Comment: See "Code Blocks" at https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to fix your formatting.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many directories the files are in.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot I'm not sure how you want handled so here's a starting point at least - this will find the files in your folders and print them prefixed with their size in bytes:

```
find folder1 folder2 -type f -printf '%s %P\n'
```

e.g. something like (just hand-editing the list from your question):

```
50000 a2021fileA123.txt
80000 a2022fileA123.txt
79000 a2021fileA124.txt
80000 a2022fileA124.txt
90000 a2021fileA125.txt
80000 a2022fileA125.txt
```

now pipe that to this awk command and it'll output the difference in sizes between the 2022 and 2021 versions of the files:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    size = $1
    year = substr($2,2,4)
    base = substr($2,6)
    bases[base]
    map[base,year] = size
}
END {
    for ( base in bases ) {
        print base, map[base,2022] - map[base,2021]
    }
}
```

```
$ find folder1 folder2 -type f -printf '%s %P\n' | awk -f tst.awk
fileA125.txt -10000
fileA123.txt 30000
fileA124.txt 1000
```

Pipe it to `sort` to get the output sorted by the size difference:

```
$ find folder1 folder2 -type f -printf '%s %P\n' | awk -f tst.awk | sort -k2,2rn
fileA123.txt 30000
fileA124.txt 1000
fileA125.txt -10000
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks so much, I think this is exactly what I need. However I am getting a syntax error:

`awk: tst.awk: line 5: syntax error at or near [`
`awk: tst.awk: line 9: syntax error at or near [`

Any advice on this?

Comment: @corazooooon As it says, you need GNU awk for this because it uses arrays of arrays

Comment: @corazooooon can you install GNU awk? It's be far the best available awk variant.

Comment: since it's just 2 hardcoded years, you can rewrite with 1-dimensional arrays - sorry I can't format nicely here!

`{
    size = $1
    year = substr($2,2,4)
    base = substr($2,6)
    switch (year)  {
        case 2021:
            map1[base] = size ;
            break
        case 2022:
            map2[base] = size ;
            break
        default: print "Unrecognised year ("year") for file: "$2
    }
}
END {
    for ( base in map2 ) {
        print base, map2[base] - map1[base]
    }
}`

Comment: @AndreBeaud good point, I went ahead and changed it to pseudo-multi-dimensional array syntax so it'll work in any awk.

Comment: @AndreBeaud by the way `switch()` is a GNU awk extension, it's not part of POSIX.

Comment: @EdMorton oops - been too long since I've been on a real Unix box. So OK, you'd have to code those by hand with `if` statements. Or as you said, just download gawk.

Comment: @EdMorton I am using WSL with debian and it turned out awk wasn't working at all. I switched to ubuntu and now it is working perfectly. Thank you so much, this was a tremendous help and my next task is to dissect this script so I can write it myself next time :)

Comment: @AndreBeaud thank you, I will give your version a try as well!

Answer (score 0):

You need `diff`

```
#!/bin/sh
cd folder1
for f in *
do
   diff $f ../folder2/$f
done
```

Comment: You should copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about.

Comment: Thanks but they have different filenames so diff returns all the files, they have a letter and year prefix depending on the folder (folder1 has a2021 and folder2 has a2022). The file suffixes match: (a2021file123.txt, a2022file123.txt), (a2021file124.txt, a2022file124.txt), etc. They have small size differences (5-10kb) which I need to sort by to locate any larger size discrepancies between 2021 and 2022. I can mash all the files into one folder if that helps. I still need to sort by size while keeping the matching files next to each other though)

Comment: @corazooooon you know 2 files with identical sizes can have 100% different contents, right? So 2 50k files with identical size could be 0 bytes different or 50k bytes different or anything in between and you can't tell by looking at the size of each. Given that, is comparing file sizes really what you want to do rather than comparing file contents?